# A Land of Vehicles

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay, geography

> I have a mountain named Ul, where cars are born.
>
> I have a great farmland, where the cars cross.
>
> I have a mountain of cauldrons, where ships are.
>
> I have a benevolent river, where airplanes are.
>
> I have a king, who is one of two "great"s.
>
> I also have a great hill and a province of light.
>
> There is the remaining one that I haven't mentioned.
>
> What am I, and what is the remaining one?

Subtle hint:

> These are cross-lingual wordplay.

Moderate hint:

> I'm in two words. The remaining one is in five letters.

Decisive hint:

> Unfortunately, I have a sibling.

Comment: I figure it has something to do with rot13(Frbhy, ohg V unir ab xabjyrqtr bs rvgure gur pbhagel vg orybatf gb, be gur pvgl :()

Comment: @Avi rot13(Gung thrff vf npghnyyl pbeerpg! Abj qb fbzr frnepu gb znxr vg n pbzbyrgr nafjre.) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are in

> South Korea

and the remaining one is

> Seoul

I have a mountain named Ul, where cars are born.

> [Ulsan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulsan) - where "san" is Korean for mountain and Ulsan has the world's largest automobile assembly plant operated by the Hyundai Motor Company.

I have a great farmland, where the cars cross.

> [Daejeon](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daejeon) translates as "grand field" and is at the crossroads of the national road transport routes.

I have a mountain of cauldrons, where ships are.

> [Busan](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busan) translates as "cauldron mountain" and is the largest port city in South Korea.

I have a benevolent river, where airplanes are.

> [Incheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incheon) translates as "kind river" and Incheon International Airport is South Korea's primary international airport.

I have a king, who is one of two "great"s.

> [Sejong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sejong_City) was named in honour of King Sejong the Great. (I think the other "Great" was Gwanggaeto)

I also have a great hill

> [Daegu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daegu) - whose name means "large hill".

and a province of light.

> [Gwangju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwangju) literally translates as Province of Light

There is the remaining one that I haven't mentioned.

> These are 7 of the 8 first-level cities in South Korea. The only one missing is Seoul, the capital.

Comment: Correct! Great job.

Comment: I should've looked at the OP's profile. Big hint.